# сортировка массива по второму значению подмассивов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
var mass = [
    ['tv', 500],
    ['mobile', 300],
    ['car', 10000]
];
```

Как отсортировать его, по второму значению каждого массива, что бы получилось так?

```
var mass = [
    ['mobile', 300],
    ['tv', 500],
    ['car', 10000]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mass.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```